# Angular side sheets with navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wonder what is the way in Angular (+Angular Material) to build functionality similar to Google Tag Manager's side-sheets (panels). You can navigate there between sheets, while those act like an overlay.

I thought about the **named outlets** but it would rather serve good for one overlay at the time. Also, it does not seem like you can pre-define the routing hierarchy, as those overlay-sheets get triggered dynamically and get stacked on each other.

In other tools, like google marketing platform, the sheets are CDK Overlays which open when path changes. Although, by directly accessing the path, the view is in full screen mode.

What kind of triggers and customisations required to achieve this behaviour?

[image]

[image]